# Invariant violation: Element type is invalid.Can not solved?

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am coding react-native.
I have also used the Appregistry.
No errors in code. 
Then I ran the / react-native run-android / and it got the error. (I had run react-native start)
Can anyone know what is happening ?
[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHg2j.png)

[index.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XkUo.png)

[App.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCw3F.png)

[Package.json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDCli.png)

Comment: Please Help me ! I stuck in this for 2 days in a row now !

Comment: I think you are not calling your function. Try this `renderScene = {this.renderScene()}`

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear. You should check all your components if there are any components you forgot to export using `export default`.

Comment: @ravibagul91  Thank you. I've tried but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @MinhDao  Thank you. I have checked all the components. All have been exported ! And it still errors :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look into your components. It is most likely that you are not exporting or importing them correctly. If you use `export default` you have to import the file as `import X from 'X'`. When using just `export` your import should look like `import { X } from 'X'`

Comment: Thanks for that. I've checked all but it still errors :(